# How to permanently save time zone in Slack profile?

Tags: slack

I've set the time zone in Slack in my profile, but it keeps being reset to "(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik". Sometimes it "survives" a page refresh, other times it doesn't. I'm logged in the whole time in Firefox on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being overridden by the workspace preferences. Go there, then to "Language & region", untick "Set time zone automatically", and set your time zone.

Unfortunately this doesn't regenerate the times shown next to messages in chat.